# Azure Redis Cache GET throughput per client connection

Tags: caching, redis, azure-redis-cache

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-planning-faq The document mentions the Throughput numbers for GETS. But there are multiple client connections possible and there is also a limit based on the Pricing tier.

Question: Is the given number on "GET Requests per second" per client connection OR after creating a max possible connection with Redis cache and running GET operations from each client?

Answer (score 1):

That's the total GETs/second regardless of the number of connections. I believe we tested with 50 connections. With lower numbers of connections, you may hit bottlenecks in the  throughput of client instances or network connections before  hit the limits of the server.

We always recommend benchmarking throughput with your application's actual architecture and workload to find actual cache capabilities for your use case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-best-practices-performance